# Add Menu Action Programatically to Visio

Tags: vba, visio, shapesheet

I'm creating a macro to add a menu button to a selected Visio shape object, so whenever the user right-clicks on the box, an option will appear and will call a macro. I created a couple of properties to the object, which will be used by the action to be called.

I can do it (**SUCCESSFULLY**) manually by using the **ShapeSheet** editor -> View Sections -> Actions -> and configuring the action with the Action value of
 `=CALLTHIS("ThisDocument.myFunction",,Prop.IPAddress)`

```
sub myFunction (shpObj as Visio.shape, strIPAddress as String) 
'working code with the functionsI want it to do. here I use the strIPAddress passed as an argument
```

What I'm trying to do is automate this by creating a macro that does the same:

```
    Public Sub AddActionToShape()
     Dim vsoShape1 As Visio.Shape
     Dim intActionRow As Integer
     'Performs this action to the selected item
     Set vsoShape1 = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection(1)
     'create row in the action section (http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/visio-help/HV080902125.aspx)
     intActionRow = vsoShape1.AddRow(visSectionAction, visRowLast, visTagDefault)
     'add action to the row (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff765539(v=office.15).aspx)
'HERE IS THE PROBLEM     
**vsoShape1.CellsSRC(visSectionAction, intActionRow, visActionAction).FormulaU = """myFunction(vsoShape1, vsoShape1.Prop.IPAddress)"""**
     vsoShape1.CellsSRC(visSectionAction, intActionRow, visActionMenu).FormulaU = """My Function"""

End Sub
```

### My question:

What value should I put on the *FormulaU* to refer to a sub routine defined in my macro, while passing parameters. If I should not be using this FormulaU attribute, please point me to the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing it like this and it works just fine.

```
Dim formula As String
formula = "=CALLTHIS([MODULE],,[ARG1],[ARG2])"
formula = Replace(formula, "[MODULE]", Chr(34) & "ThisDocument.myFunction" & Chr(34))
formula = Replace(formula, "[ARG1]", "Prop.IPAddress")
formula = Replace(formula, "[ARG2]", "Prop.Username")

'After the formula has been created, apply it to the row
shape.CellsSRC(visSectionAction, rowBeingEdited, visActionAction).formula = formula
```

Comment: I have added this code in the addin (in Visual Studio) and the method is not getting called when I click the context menu option. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You should set FormulaU exactly to the content to which you set it manually. That is, to

```
CALLTHIS("ThisDocument.myFunction",,Prop.IPAddress)
```

Try:

```
vsoShape1.CellsSRC(visSectionAction, intActionRow, visActionMenu).FormulaU = _
    "CALLTHIS(""ThisDocument.myFunction"",,Prop.IPAddress)"
```