# unable to find few visio objects on visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visio, add-on

I am trying to write a visio application. If I write in Macro (within visio app), I get all objects. However, when I try to write same code in Visual Studio 2019, I cant find references. Like ActiveWindow or visSectionAction. I am trying to follow this: [Add Menu Action Programatically to Visio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811268/add-menu-action-programatically-to-visio)

What references am I missing. I added nuget package, added office object library.
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Visio object model from a .NET application, you need to add a reference to Visio type library to that application. This is `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio`. You could start over in the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/visio-object-model-overview

The global VBA objects, like `ActiveWindow`, are available as `app.ActiveWindow` (assuming the "app" is the root Visio Application object you access). In case of an Add-In:

```cs
var w = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow
```

or in case you need to access from a method of the add-in:

```
var w = Application.ActiveWindow
```

Enumerations should be prefixed with its type: `VisSectionIndices.visSectionAction`.

Please note that the answer in the linked question explains how to add a menu item to a **shape**, not to the application. If you want to extend application menu rather than shape menu (?), you need to add your menu item to the ribbon definition.